# PHP + Session doesn't login at first time

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication

My login system only logs in if I do it 2 times. In the first time, it doesn't log in (automatically).
I have a simple form with username and password, with `action="login.php"`, which as you might think has the whole code for verify login, etc..and then, in the end, if everything is ok:

```
Cookie::set('page-main-login-cookie', serialize($arr), time()+60);
header('location: ../index.php');
```

In the `index.php` (which contains the form that calls `login.php`), in the top of the page:

```
ob_start(); session_start(); include('cookies.php'); include('sessions.php');
```

After the `</html>` tag:

```
if(Cookie::Exists('page-main-login-cookie')){
    $data = unserialize(stripslashes($_COOKIE['page-main-login-cookie']));
    if($data['status'] == 1){   
        Cookie::set('email', $data['email'], time() + (86400 * 7));
        Session::set('email', $data['email']);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> page_redirect(); </script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> page_error(); </script>";
    }
    Cookie::Delete('page-main-login-cookie', time() - 3600);
}
```

And while I'm writing this topic I wonder if the problem might be in the javascript. The code for `page_redirect()` is the following:

```
function page_redirect(){
    alert("Done!");
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.reload();
    }, 1500);
}
```

What have I tried so far?

1. Changed `header('location: ../index.php');` to `header('location: http://www.mysite.com');`
2. Added `session_write_close();` after `Session::set('email', $data['email']);`

None of them worked.

Comment: I think the problem is with the placement of redirect code. If you did the check and redirect before `<html>` then this will be fine.

Comment: You realize someone can easily store any arbitrary email address in the session by simply creating their own cookie? And if that is the only means of authorization, that user can log in to your app with any email he/she likes.

Comment: @Janoz, this is an example. Actually, my code has the following: `Cookie::set('email', $data['email'], time() + (86400 * 7)); // 7 days
Session::set('email', $data['email']);
Session::set('name', $data['name']);
Session::set('id', $data['id']);`
But tell me, do I continue having security problems with this?

Comment: Definitely! $data is serialized into the cookie. Cookie is stored clientside and can be manipulated easily. I can make a cookie named 'page-main-login-cookie' and put in my own version of a serialized data map. Why don't you just store that data directly into the session instead of passing it through the untrusted client.

Comment: I don't get it. $data is not serialized into the cookie (at least not all the values). Only the value $data['email'] is inserted into the cookie. I have the cookies because of the time of the session..7 days logged, after that, it needs to log in again.

Comment: Btw, I have this verification in the top: `if(!Cookie::Exists('email') || Cookie::Get('email') != Session::Get('Email')){ Session::Destroy(); }`

Comment: make var_dump of (Cookie::Get('email')) and Session::Get('Email') ant give the information here

Comment: Where does $data come from? Exactly : $data = unserialize(stripslashes($_COOKIE['page-main-login-cookie']));

Comment: @Janoz, see my last answer to sergio. I do verify if the data is equal to the session.

Comment: But why pass it in a cookie when you can just set it in login.php? It's just over complicated, unsafe and error prone. Although with that check I can't log in with an arbitrary email, I still can change every other item in $data (id and name for example). If id is used to identify the user later on I can still impersonate anybody.

Comment: The cookie is instantly deleted. `Cookie::set('page-main-login-cookie', serialize($arr), time()+60);` its a cookie of 60 seconds. After put the cookie I automatically redirect to the page which verifies if the Cookie exists, performs the operations and deletes the Cookie. How are you going to change the Cookie in 1 second?

Obs: I'm trying to learn/understand your point, don't see my answers as someone who doesn't care.

Comment: You assume you can trust the browser completely. You can't. I can just do a log in request on your login page and ignore the redirect header by using curl. I can take my time constructing the new cookie, make it in advance or make it on the fly before requesting your index.php. GET, POST and COOKIE vars can ALWAYS be changed by the user. Never trust the content. Obs: And I'm trying to teach, so no offence taken.

Comment: Looking at your previous answer, this is the right code? http://pastebin.com/BQQSv7Zq

Comment: Btw, I've implemented that, and I think its way better. If that is what you were thinking, then thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Probably** because your log in code comes **after** your html, so it appears like you are not logged in even though the script does log you in at the end of the script.

**Typically** you would want to keep your PHP and HTML as separate as possible (in different files), and do all of your PHP business logic first, then output all the HTML.

Comment: Well, I've changed my code to the top, and now the user logs successfully at first time..but if he refreshs the page, the login disappears.

Comment: I thing there are can be some mistakes in your code, maybe in this line:  Cookie::Delete('page-main-login-cookie', time() - 3600);

Comment: No, the problem is not there. The problem is on this line: `if(!isset($_COOKIE['email'])){ 
  Session::Destroy(); 
 }`

If I remove this it works..but I don't get it. And I need this verification..

Comment: make var_dump of (Cookie::Get('email')) and Session::Get('Email') ant give the information here

Comment: Solved. The problem was on the conditions. `if(Session::Exists('email')){
 if(!Cookie::Exists('email')){
  Session::Destroy();
 }else{
  if(Cookie::Get('email') != Session::Get('email')){
   Session::Destroy();
   Cookie::Delete($_COOKIE['email'], time() - 3600);
  }
 }
}`

I will accept your answer as correct, since it solved my topic problem. Thanks.