# PHP load javascript function on top of file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, alertify

This topic is the follow-up of this one [PHP + Session doesn't login at first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564567/php-session-doesnt-login-at-first-time).

I've solved my issue of Cookies/Sessions by changing the code to the top of everything, before `<html>`, previously I was writing my php code after the `</html>` tag.

With this change I've lost the output of javascript plugin (http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/).

Simple example:

```
if(Cookie::Exists('page-main-login-cookie')){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>page_add_success('OK')</script>";
}
```

This no longer works, I do understand why, because the javascript files are AFTER the `<html>`, and I'm calling the function before.

```
<script src="js/alertify/js/alertify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function page_add_success(msg){
        alertify.success(msg);
    }
</script>
```

I've found some topics on stackoverflow about including the right scripts before calling the function in php. Something like:

```
<?php 
    echo "<script src='js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>";
    echo "<script src='js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js'></script>";
    echo "<script src='js/alertify/js/alertify.min.js'></script>";
?>
```

So, in the end, the top of my file would be:

```
include('headscript.php');

if(Cookie::Exists('page-main-login-cookie')){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>page_add_success('OK')</script>";
}
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function page_add_success(msg){
            alertify.success(msg);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

But the function continues to be on below of the PHP..and doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this helps,

instead of echoing it in php, pass it to a variable and use after the header.

eg:

```
  <?php 
   if(Cookie::Exists('page-main-login-cookie')){
    $page= "<script type='text/javascript'>page_add_success('OK')</script>";
        }
  ?>
```

and then echo it after the header using,

```
   <?php echo $page; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <?php include('headscript.php');?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function page_add_success(msg){
        alertify.success(msg);
    }

    <?php
    if(Cookie::Exists('page-main-login-cookie')){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>page_add_success('OK')</script>";
    }?>

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you cant use HTML tags before your html tag. Ie. you would have to echo the script tags inside the html tag, and more preferably inside the head.

Also it is bad practice to use single quotes (') for html attributes. double quotes (") are prefered as the standard.

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/alertify/js/alertify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function page_add_success(msg) {
            alertify.success(msg);
        }
    </script>

    <?php
        if(Cookie::Exists('page-main-login-cookie')) {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">page_add_success('OK');</script>";
        }
    ?>
    </head>
    ....
```

You could always use the jQuery.cookie (http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) plugin to read the cookie in javascript on pageload avoiding useing php at all.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/alertify/js/alertify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function page_add_success(msg) {
            alertify.success(msg);
        }

        $(document).ready(
            function() {
                if($.cookie('page-main-login-cookie')) {
                    page_add_success('OK');
                }
            }
        );
    </script>

    </head>
    ....
```

Comment: I don't want to use jqueryCookie because of browser compatibility. Your first code, I've already tried it and gives me this error on google chrome console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null` http://s16.postimg.org/a4t3xv75v/Sem_t_tulo.jpg

Comment: That would suggest to me that there is a problem with alertify.min.js on line 2 trying to add an element into thee page. Which would in turn suggest that either the script is broken or that the elemnt it is trying to append to doesnt exist at the time of calling the function. Try changing your php echo to -> echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(function() { page_add_success('OK'); });</script>"; <- and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

this should help

do not use this:

```
include('headscript.php');

if(Cookie::Exists('page-main-login-cookie')){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>page_add_success('OK')</script>";
}
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function page_add_success(msg){
            alertify.success(msg);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
 </html>
```

but try to use this:

```
include('headscript.php');

<html>
    <head>
    <?php
    if(Cookie::Exists('page-main-login-cookie')){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>page_add_success('OK')</script>";
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function page_add_success(msg){
            alertify.success(msg);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
 </html>
```